# Excel Worksheet function for 2 variables to Equal statement

Tags: excel, excel-2010, worksheet-function, worksheet

I am looking for more of a worksheet based solution, VBA to come soon possibly.

I need the sheet to have a reference to another sheet and then display a value in a row based on 2 other rows.  Basically what I mean is

I need sheet1 A1 to be equal to whatever number is in sheet2 Column c in a non specific cell, based on numbers in sheet 2 column A and B.

So If my Sheet 2 looked like

```
A     B     C
1     1     18.5
2     1     17
```

So A1 would need to equal whatever value in row c that has A and B = 1 or A=2 and B=1

Sorry if this is a bit confusing. Thanks for any help.

Comment: but in your example, both conditions are satisified, so which one do you want?

Comment: I guess I meant that A2 could have something like 2 and 1 and A3 could be 4 and 2

Comment: so in that case, you would want to return 18.5 (since A2 = 2 and B2 = 1 and A3 = 4 and B3 = 2 does not satisfy the criteria)?

Comment: The data sheet can be lots of things like b can be 1-19 and C can be 1 to 12

Comment: okay. the back and forth is not making it any *clearer*. Please post pictures of sample data sheets and what you want the output to look like. That will make it easiest to help you accomplish the goal.

Comment: http://imgur.com/eFhbl1I

Comment: The above Image is of what the data set would look like So i need A1 in a different sheet to look through for a row in SHeet2 for a Row where both B and C equal a specified Number could be 1 and 1 or it could be 19 and 2, (These I can specify myself in the function) and then it needs to take the value in D for the actual value of A1

Comment: thanks for the image and explanation. see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Given how the data is set up in your picture, this formula will work.

`=INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,MATCH(1&1,Sheet2!B:B&Sheet2!C:C,0))`

Be sure to enter it as an array formula `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`

`1&1` as the first argument in the match formula is just hardcoded numbers, can be changed at will, or cell referenced.

Inspiration for this answer, provided from this [guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214142)

Comment: I used that same site just a little while ago for a different question here.  I failed to see how it could be modified to work here.  It just opened up a lot of possibilities.  I bow to your ingenuity.

Comment: And I appreciate yours as well @ScottCraner :) ... I think being a good programmer is more about keen googling sleuthing than anything else these days!

Comment: @ScottHoltzman This yields a #N/A error upon entering it into the cell, it highlights the correct columns but yields no result

Comment: Two questions: Did you enter it as an **array** formula? Is the data in your `Sheet2` numeric and are you entering numbers into the first argument of the `Match` function, or is the data in `Sheet2` text (even if it looks like numbers)?

Comment: I am fairly sure I entered it as an array formula, but I am not 100% sure how to know. Also, it is in text form.

Comment: @R.Green - You can tell if it's an array formula, because you will see `{}` around the formula after you hit `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` in the Formula Bar. But the issue is that it's in text format. To solve this, enter the first arguments in the `Match` wrapped in quotes (`Match("1"&"1"`)

Comment: So that does work, Thank you, now the only thing is i have like 27000 lines of data, so is there a way to make it a cell reference even if the values are text?

Comment: @R.Green - Yes, just make it a cell reference and format the cells to Text (or enter text into the cells with a leading `'`.)

Comment: Awesome thank you!. Now is there any reason as to why it would just stop working at a certain number. also there are 3 variables now, so A needs to be something and B and C then find D, and it still works I have it set up as references to cells so I can click and drag the formula and for the first half of the data it works perfect but when I hit 11 for example, it starts re arranging order so it should be where it Displays D if A=11 B =1 and C=1 but instead it gives me the D value for A=1,B=1 and C=11. SO it must not see them as individual numbers or something, the cell refs work great though

Comment: Or @ScottHoltzman for examply if it were to be "12" & "1" & "1" for A and B and C respectively it finds the D value for  a column where A is 1 B is 2 and C is 11.....                  Referring to the problem in my last comment of course

Comment: @R.Green you could put something to denote the cells, like "|",  This would work, `=INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,MATCH(12&"|" &1&"|" &1,Sheet2!A:A &"|" &Sheet2!B:B&"|"&Sheet2!C:C,0))`.  This puts a `|` between each value and it will force it to see each cell separately.

Comment: The "Great Scotts" gotta' stick together.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a helper column.  Add a column before A and put the following formula:

```
=B1 & C1
```

[image]

Then on sheet one I set it up like this:

[image]

so the formula is:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1&B1,Sheet2!$A$1:$D$2,4,FALSE)
```

Comment: So in your second picture A and B are in both sheets, they should only be in sheet 2. I canmonly have the value from colum C get transferred, also I dont think the helper column is something I can use because of the way my data is set up as it gets imported, it needs to be presentable for the most part, and this may make it confusing

Comment: @R.Green You can hide the helper column. The second picture was just showing how to use the vlookup,  You can certainly just have the vlookup. `=VLOOKUP("11",Sheet2!$A$1:$D$2,4,FALSE)`